# Secure Azure App Service with AAD Security Group via URL Authorization rules

Tags: azure, security, azure-web-app-service

Following the blog post [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/11/17/url-authorization-rules/), there is support for securing App Services from Azure with AAD security groups (via Easy auth + authorization.json) but there is no documentation/sample around how do to so.

Does anyone know if that functionality is GA ready and if there's any way to enable it (even if not GA)?

Using the example authorization.json from the post it does enable auto-redirect to a login page based on the rules:

```
{
    "routes":[{
        "path_prefix" : "/",
        "policies" : { "unauthenticated_action" : "AllowAnonymous" }
    },{
        "path_prefix" : "/_admin",
        "policies": { "unauthenticated_action" : "RedirectToLoginPage" }
    }]
}
```

But I don't know how to specify which users should be allowed after they login

Comment: I can not find documentation/blog about restricting access to specified URL routes to Azure AD Security Groups too. You can try to write custom code to get current user identity and restrict access to certain resources based on the group that user belongs to.